# Python printing list in columns

Tags: python

How can I print in Python values from list in columns?

I sorted them, but I don't know how to print them in two ways
For instance:

```
list=['apricot','banana','apple','car','coconut','baloon','bubble']
```

**First one:**

```
apricot      bubble     ...
apple        car        
baloon       coconut
```

**Second way:**

```
apricot    apple     baloon   
bubble     car      coconut
```

I also want to align everything with ljust/rjust.

I tried something like this:

```
print " ".join(word.ljust(8) for word in list)
```

but it displays only like in first example. I don't know if it is proper way to do this.

Comment: There is not built in way to do this, you'll have to program it yourself.

Comment: And your attempt to solve this?

Comment: I tried something like this: print " ".join(word.ljust(8) for word in list) but it displays only like in first example. I don't know it is proper way to do this.

Comment: What are your requirements? Should the function compute by itself the number of columns or should it be a second argument to your function?

Comment: I don't mind giving it as a second argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the_list = ['apricot','banana','apple','car','coconut','baloon','bubble']
num_columns = 3

for count, item in enumerate(sorted(the_list), 1):
    print item.ljust(10),
    if count % num_columns == 0:
        print
```

output:

```
apple      apricot    baloon    
banana     bubble     car       
coconut
```

**UPDATE**:
Here is the comprehensive solution that addresses both examples you have given. I have created a function for this and i have commented the code so that its clear to understand what it is being done.

```
def print_sorted_list(data, rows=0, columns=0, ljust=10):
    """
    Prints sorted item of the list data structure formated using
    the rows and columns parameters
    """

    if not data:
        return

    if rows:
        # column-wise sorting
        # we must know the number of rows to print on each column
        # before we print the next column. But since we cannot
        # move the cursor backwards (unless using ncurses library)
        # we have to know what each row with look like upfront
        # so we are basically printing the rows line by line instead
        # of printing column by column
        lines = {}
        for count, item in enumerate(sorted(data)):
            lines.setdefault(count % rows, []).append(item)
        for key, value in sorted(lines.items()):
            for item in value:
                print item.ljust(ljust),
            print
    elif columns:
        # row-wise sorting
        # we just need to know how many columns should a row have
        # before we print the next row on the next line.
        for count, item in enumerate(sorted(data), 1):
            print item.ljust(ljust),
            if count % columns == 0:
                print
    else:
        print sorted(data)  # the default print behaviour


if __name__ == '__main__':
    the_list = ['apricot','banana','apple','car','coconut','baloon','bubble']
    print_sorted_list(the_list)
    print_sorted_list(the_list, rows=3)
    print_sorted_list(the_list, columns=3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Could you tell me, if there is a way to print it like i have shown in first example?

Comment: @bartekshadow I have updated my answer to include a solution that also cater for your first example.

Comment: @dopstar this in now broken in python 3 which needs print(). I'm a python newb and tried just adding () to your print statements eg. print(item.ljust(ljust),) only that breaks it causing the result that All output is on the LHS in 1 column only.only. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance...